# Selector for siblings of a specific element that match a condition

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following scenario:

```
<table>
  <tr class="header">
  <tr class="data1">
  <tr class="data2">
  <tr class="data3">
  <tr class="header">
  <tr class="data1">
  <tr class="data2">
</table>
```

I want to change the text color of the `data` elements under the first header to blue, and the `data` elements under the second header to red.

I've tried various `nth-child` and adjacent sibling (`+`) but all my tries are incomplete.

`tr[class^=data]` gets all of elements I want to affect, but I need them in two groups.

I don't know how many `data` elements I will have, I do know I have only 2 `header`

*I can't use javascript/jquery here, just selectors*

Comment: Have you tried the general sibling combinator? `~`

Comment: No, never heard of it, thanks!

Comment: Do you need `tr[class^=data]`? Will there ever be `tr` elements which do not have the `dataxxx` classes, other than the `.header` classes? Because attribute selectors like `^=` are very slow and depending how large your tables are could have a visible impact.

Comment: Anyway, if you are simply using `tr[class^=data]` to not target the `.header` you can just use `tr:not(.header)` instead, which is a lot faster. .i.e: `.header ~ tr:not(.header) { color: red;} .header ~ .header ~ tr { color: blue; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that you will only have two header rows, you can just have the styles for the second set of data rows override those of the first set of data rows:

```css
.header ~ tr[class^=data] {
  color: #f00;
}

.header ~ .header ~ tr[class^=data] {
  color: #00f;
}
```

If you can modify the HTML, just group your header and data rows into tbody elements and you won't have to worry about carefully selecting just the rows associated with each header:

```css
tbody:first-child td {
  color: #f00;
}

tbody:last-child td {
  color: #00f;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="header"><th>Header
    <tr class="data1"><td>Data1
    <tr class="data2"><td>Data2
    <tr class="data3"><td>Data3
  <tbody>
    <tr class="header"><th>Header
    <tr class="data1"><td>Data1
    <tr class="data2"><td>Data2
</table>
```

Comment: Curiosity: do all browsers auto-close tags?

Comment: @Andrei Gheorghiu: More precisely, the end tags are all optional (except for </table>). They're only mandatory in XHTML. When in doubt, use the end tags anyway - I'm only leaving them out for the sake of brevity and because I know what I'm doing.

Comment: @Andrei Gheorghiu: Yes. The logic is the same with that of the p and li elements.

Comment: I usually upvote your answers and I'm humbled by your activity here. I also like how you always explain the principle. But this time, at least in theory, I can't. *"Overriding"* has nothing to do with it in the first case. It's about *"specificity"*. If you inverse the two rules they still work.

Comment: @Andrei Gheorghiu: Specificity being at play here is *precisely* why overriding of styles takes place - because the more specific selector matches a subset of the elements that would be matched by the less specific selector. The data rows following the second header row are all matched by the less specific selector (since they're all following siblings of at least one .header), so you would need the rule with the more specific selector to override that, which is fine since the goal is to apply styles to each set of data rows anyway.